# Detect first character in list with macros

Tags: expansion, xstring, comparison

I have a comma separated list that I process with `\foreach`. This has been working for quite some time. Decided to make a minor tweak and that is to allow for an optional leading `*` in which case I want to remove the * and color that particular line in red. This seems to work, except for the case where the content (`\the\MyListB`) contains other macros.

### Question:

What changes do I need to make to `\DisplayListFormatted` so that I can process `\DisplayListFormatted{\the\MyListB}` and have the line beginning with the asterix be in red?

---

The output of the MWE below (with the critical line commented out) is:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtoks{\MyListA}
\newtoks{\MyListB}

\MyListA={
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with macros and "math" $sin^2 x + cos^2 x \ne 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other important comment.,
}

\MyListB={
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with \emph{macros} and math $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \ne 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other \emph{important} comment.,
}

\newcommand{\DisplayListUnformatted}[1]{%
    \edef\MyExpandedList{#1}%
    \foreach \x in \MyExpandedList {%
        \par\hspace*{2.0ex}\x%
    }
}%

\newcommand{\DisplayListFormatted}[1]{%
    \edef\MyExpandedList{#1}%
    \foreach \x in \MyExpandedList {%
        \par\hspace*{2.0ex}%
        %\noexpandarg% <--Can process \MyListB if uncomment this, but asterix detection fails!
        \IfBeginWith{\x}{*}{%
            \StrGobbleLeft{\x}{1}[\xNoAsterix]%
            \color{red}\xNoAsterix%
        }{%
            \x%
        }%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}


Displaying the list works:
\par\verb|\the\MyListA|
\DisplayListUnformatted{\the\MyListA}
\par\verb|\the\MyListB|
\DisplayListUnformatted{\the\MyListB}

But want to extract the asterix:
\par\verb|\the\MyListA|
\DisplayListFormatted{\the\MyListA}
\par\verb|\the\MyListB|
%\DisplayListFormatted{\the\MyListB}% <--- How do I get this to work!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand `\x` once.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtoks{\MyListA}
\newtoks{\MyListB}

\MyListA={
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with macros and "math" $sin^2 x + cos^2 x \ne 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other important comment.,
}

\MyListB={
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with \emph{macros} and math $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \ne 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other \emph{important} comment.,
}

\newcommand{\DisplayListUnformatted}[1]{%
    \edef\MyExpandedList{#1}%
    \foreach \x in \MyExpandedList {%
        \par\hspace*{2.0ex}\x
    }
}

\newcommand{\DisplayListFormatted}[1]{%
    \edef\MyExpandedList{#1}%
    \foreach \x in \MyExpandedList {%
        \par\hspace*{2.0ex}%
        \noexpandarg
        \expandafter\IfBeginWith\expandafter{\x}{*}{%
            \expandafter\StrGobbleLeft\expandafter{\x}{1}[\xNoAsterix]%
            \color{red}\xNoAsterix%
        }{%
            \x
        }%
    }%
}


\begin{document}


Displaying the list works:
\par\verb|\the\MyListA|
\DisplayListUnformatted{\the\MyListA}
\par\verb|\the\MyListB|
\DisplayListUnformatted{\the\MyListB}

But want to extract the asterix:
\par\verb|\the\MyListA|
\DisplayListFormatted{\the\MyListA}
\par\verb|\the\MyListB|
\DisplayListFormatted{\the\MyListB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also enjoy an `xparse` implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_new:c { g_peter_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_gset:cn { g_peter_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayListFormatted}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { g_peter_list_#1_clist }
   {
    \par
    \hspace*{1em}
    \tl_if_eq:nfTF { * } { \tl_head:n { ##1 } }
     { \textcolor{red} { \tl_tail:n { ##1 } } }
     { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newlist{A}{
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with macros and "math" $sin^2 x + cos^2 x \ne 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other important comment.,
}

\newlist{B}{
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with \emph{macros} and math $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \ne 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other \emph{important} comment.,
}

\begin{document}

List A
\DisplayListFormatted{A}

List B
\DisplayListFormatted{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since your formatting activation is done using `*`, you could use a macro-style approach to detect it using `\@ifstar`, similar to how `\chapter` conditions to `\@chapter` or `\@schapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor,xcolor}

\newtoks{\MyListA}
\newtoks{\MyListB}

\MyListA={
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with macros and ``math'' $sin^2 x + cos^2 x \neq 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other important comment.
}

\MyListB={
    2016-05-25: {Some plain comment, but has commas so is brace grouped}.,
   *2016-05-26: Some text with \emph{macros} and math $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \neq 0$.,
    2016-05-27: Some other \emph{important} comment.
}

\makeatletter
\def\processitem{\@ifstar\processitem@i\processitem@ii}
\def\processitem@i#1\@nil{\color{red}#1}
\def\processitem@ii#1\@nil{#1}

\newcommand{\DisplayListUnformatted}[1]{%
  \edef\MyExpandedList{#1}%
  \foreach \x in \MyExpandedList {%
    \par\hspace*{2.0ex}\x%
  }
}%

\newcommand{\DisplayListFormatted}[1]{%
  \edef\MyExpandedList{#1}%
  \foreach \x in \MyExpandedList {%
    \par\hspace*{2.0ex}%
    \expandafter\processitem\x\@nil
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Displaying the list works:
\par\verb|\the\MyListA|
\DisplayListUnformatted{\the\MyListA}

\par\verb|\the\MyListB|
\DisplayListUnformatted{\the\MyListB}

But want to extract the asterisk:
\par\verb|\the\MyListA|
\DisplayListFormatted{\the\MyListA}

\par\verb|\the\MyListB|
\DisplayListFormatted{\the\MyListB}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I attempted to use the `s` argument type of `xparse` but was not able to get it to work.

Comment: @PeterGrill: [This is what I used](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lz2K5.png) and it worked.

Comment: I think I was missing the `\expandafter` before calling `\processitem`. My usual expansion headaches!! :-)